# OxyPlot: SkiaSharp vs SharpDX

Tags: c#, performance, sharpdx, oxyplot, skiasharp

I am trying to use OxyPlot with .NET Core 3.0 to show a plot with thousands of LineSeries, and each one of these LineSeries containing several hundreds of Points.

As this is so much data I am trying both SkiaSharp renderer and also SharpDX (https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-sharpdx). However, I am not very sure about which one to choose, as oxyplot-sharpdx development seems to be stuck since some months ago, and SkiaSharp is pretty new.

Which one would you recommend me? Has somebody performed some performance comparisson between them?

To put some example about what I am trying to achieve, here is some code:

```
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "Hello SharpDX from WPF" };
        
        model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Bottom });
        model.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis { Position = AxisPosition.Left, Title="Left Axis Title" });
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)
        {
            var lineSeries = new LineSeries ();
            for (int j = 0; j < 300; ++j)
            {
                lineSeries.Points.Add(new DataPoint(j, j * i % 2));
            }
            model.Series.Add(lineSeries);
        }

        this.Model = model;
    }

    public PlotModel Model { get; }
```

Any help would be really apreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case somebody else is also facing this.

After digging into this I have decided to move on with SkiaSharp, as it has shown (at least in our tests) to be slightly faster than SharpDX.

For these tests we plotted 5000 lines, each one of them with 300 points.

The average time for 3 measures with *SkiaSharp* was **23.91** seconds. Meanwhile, with *SharpDX* the average time was **25.8** sconds.

Also the development seems to be more active in the SkiaSharp case.

These two facts have lead us to make this choice.

I hove this answer can help somebody else.